# Resistance across different terminals of a material of variable resistivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-current, charge, electrical-resistance

I have seen many questions in my book trying to find Resistance across different materials of variable resistivity(by integration).
For example, consider the following :

[image: Resistance]

I can find resistance across A and B which comes out to be $\frac{\rho l}{A}$, where l is length of wire and A is area of the left face.
But now, If I want to find resistance across **C** and **D**, I am thinking of taking a rectangular Area at a distance **x** from one side and then integrate.
Now, here are some of my doubts:

1. Will the Resistance across **E** and **F** will be same as across **C** and **D**? I think it would be since path followed is same but can I get a more clear view of it to convince myself?
2. Considering the second body(Consider it to be of thickness **d** down the plane and the body shape is parabolic), I can find resistance across **X** and **Y** but will the resistance across **P** and **Y** will be same?
   I can't understand this because may be path followed is different.

Comment: I'm not an electrical expert, but the CD and EF resistances seem more complex than something that can be found by simple integration.  The current will take all possible paths, with more charge flowing where resistance is lower. EF would have higher resistance because it is thicker there. I think you would need to solve Maxwell's Equations via Finite Element Model or search for a graphical solution to that geometry (or better yet, build a model of it and use a multimeter). It is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: @RC_23 What about second figure? Can we find resistance across that using integration?

Comment: Note that when you found the resistance between A and B, you implicitly assumed you were making contact with the entire side at A and the entire side at B. (This is necessary for the current to flow in straight lines so that the integration is valid.)  You can’t do this with C and D because they’re the same surface.